# Laravel 5.2 - cannot set cookie

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and tried the following code to set cookie, but the cookie is not set. I checked by seeing Chrome/Safari/FireFox dev tool and also by calling Cookie::get('test') in 'cookie-test' blade template.

```
class SampleController extends Controller {
  public function index() {
    echo 'setting cookie...';
    $response = new Response(view('cookie-test'));
    $response->withCookie('name', 'value', 60);
    return $response;
  }
}
```

I also tried other ways introduced on the official document, such as

```
$response = new Illuminate\Http\Response('Hello World');
$response->withCookie('name', 'value', $minutes);
return $response;
```

,

```
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('name', 'value'));
```

,

```
Cookie::queue(cookie('name', 'value', 60))
```

and so on, referencing stackoverflow answers too.

Is there anything I'm missing? Any configuration I need to setup in advance? Any good ways to debug this problem?

I'd appreciate any advice, thank you.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause. Using echo() or var_dump() before returning $response will prevent the application from setting cookie. I used var_dump() in a class called by the constructor of the above Controller for debug, but after I deleted the var_dump() line, cookie was set successfully.

Comment: this was also happening to me, and after hours going through all other stackoverflow threads and laravel Cookie:: methods, finally found this one, and removing my var dump solved it for me